# pyplot hist, plotting binned data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Here is the code non-binned plot of the data.

```
link_weights = [float(s)/float(k) for s,k in zip(strengths, degrees)]
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig2.add_subplot(121)
ax.set_xlabel('degree [k]')
ax.set_ylabel('Average link weight <w>')
ax.scatter(degrees, link_weights, alpha=0.5)

ax = fig2.add_subplot(122)
ax.set_xlabel('degree [k]')
ax.set_ylabel('Average link weight <w>')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.scatter(degrees, link_weights, alpha=0.5)
fig2.savefig("figure-1b-1.pdf", ftype='pdf')
```

[image]

I want to plot histogram of binned data (bin-averaged versions of the plots). I managed to create binned data but stuck with plotting.

```
n_bins = 20
fig3 = plt.figure()
ax = fig3.add_subplot(121)
bin_means, bin_edges, _= stats.binned_statistic(link_weights, degrees, 
                                      statistic='mean', bins=n_bins)
```

I need to know how to plot bin_means as a histogram (lin x-axis and log x-axis). My initial attempt is below but it failed.

```
ax.hist(bin_means, n_bins, normed=True, histtype='bar')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How did your attempt "fail"?

Comment: Error:
    ax.hist(bin_means, n_bins, normed=True, histtype='bar')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8326, in hist
    m, bins = np.histogram(x[i], bins, weights=w[i], **hist_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 165, in histogram
    'max must be larger than min in range parameter.')
AttributeError: max must be larger than min in range parameter.

Comment: Please add the error message to your question. The problem is possibly that `ax.hist` will *compute* and plot your histogram. If my suspicion is correct and you want a 2d histogram, then check out `ax.hist2d` with *your raw data as input*!

Comment: I need a bar graph with length of each bar representing the average of link_weights in the corresponding range of degrees. To my understanding i don't need a 2d-histogram.

Comment: I see. Yeah, you don't. But you also don't need `ax.hist`:) That could only give you the distribution of a single variable. I think what you need is a bar plot, i.e. [`ax.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar), probably something like `ax.bar(bin_edges[:-1],bin_means)` or something like that.

Comment: Any luck with this problem?